# sequence contains no elements Error Max()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am Getting:

> sequence contains no elements

```
private int? GetPrecedingSibling(int? contentid,int? templateid)
{
    var value = _sequenceTemplateItemService.Query(e => e.templateId == templateid && e.contentItemId == contentid).Select(t => t.id).Max();
    if (value != 0)
        return value; 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: With C#6 you can easily promote `int` to `int?` by using the `?.` operator, thus reducing the whole method to `return _sequenceTemplateItemService.Query(e => e.templateId == templateid && e.contentItemId == contentid).Max(t => t?.id);`

Answer (score 62):

Your query is not returning any `id`s. That is why the exception. If your `id` type is `int?` then use `DefaultIfEmpty()` like:

```
var value = _sequenceTemplateItemService.Query(e => e.templateId == templateid && e.contentItemId == contentid)
                    .Select(t => t.id)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .Max();
```

The other options is to check for `Any` records and then return `Max` or null.

```
var tempResult = _sequenceTemplateItemService.Query(e => e.templateId == templateid && e.contentItemId == contentid)
                    .Select(t => t.id);

if (tempResult.Any())
{
    return tempResult.Max();
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The above query is behaving like OR instead of AND operation 
What am I missing here

   SELECT TOP 1 MAX(id) FROM sequenceTemplateItems sti 
WHERE sti.templateid = (some value) OR sti.contentitemid = null
should return Null and not a value

Comment: I used profiler to monitor and it is creating this 

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id]
    FROM [dbo].[sequenceTemplateItems] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[templateId] = @p__linq__0) AND (([Extent1].[contentItemId] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[contentItemId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=12742,@p__linq__1=NULL 


But I want it to run like this 

   SELECT TOP 1 MAX(id) FROM sequenceTemplateItems sti 
WHERE sti.templateid = 12740 AND sti.contentitemid = null